# Unable to attach picture to text message

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I can no longer attach a picture to my text messages. It used to work, now when I try to do it, it says I have to sign into Samsung Link first. What to do?

Android Version 4.4.2

Comment: Please elaborate. Which messaging app are you using? You tagged the question as "Galaxy S", if this is your device, please tell us which Android OS version it's running. Stock? Rooted? Custom ROM?  What exactly happens when you try to attach images?

Comment: We need a LOT more information.  Start off by answering every question @Chahk asked, along with the troubleshooting steps that you have tried.

Comment: s-3, default app that looks like an envelope

Comment: I also have an S3, also with the standard messaging app, just attached a Gallery image no problem, and sent. Never received a Samsung Link warning. Can you send a message without an image? Is your network connection good? Does it go through?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a segment from the description of [Samsung Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.pcw&hl=en):
** AllShare Play is now Samsung Link. Continue to log-in with your Samsung Account to access your pictures, videos, and documents previously stored on AllShare Play.*

Access & Play Content across Smart Devices, Anytime Anywhere
Samsung Link enables users to access & play content saved on other devices over a wireless access point as well as over the internet.
This gives me the impression that the item you are sharing is an AllShare Item, possibly shared by you long ago, without your remembering it. It may even have been shared to you by a different AllShare user, and belongs to that account.

(This is Just a Guess) To attach it, it would make sense that you have to log in as the accountholder that owns it.

Comment: This sounds correct.  I'm thinking he's attaching a picture from Link storage.